# C Socket - Determine data length

Tags: c, sockets, networking, tcp

I wrote a little SocketWrapper in **C** just for learning and it works. I'm sending a GET-Request and receiving a buffer[1024]. But the content I would like to read is often longer than 1024. How can I determine the length and receive the whole data?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include "lib/output.h"
#include "lib/network.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
debug_verbose = true;

struct IPv4_CLIENT client;
client = socketIPv4("google.com", 80);

if(socketIPv4_connect(client) < 0) {
    error("Connect failed!");
    return -1;
}   

char send_buffer[256];
bzero(send_buffer, 256);

printline("Send: ");
fgets(send_buffer, 255, stdin);

socketIPv4_write(client, send_buffer);

char receive_buffer[1024];
socketIPv4_read(client, receive_buffer, 1024);
hexdump(receive_buffer, 1024);

socketIPv4_close(client);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's why there's an HTTP [protocol specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) -- it tells you how to do things like that. (What version of HTTP are you trying to implement? The rules for 1.1 are much more complex -- you *must* support chunked encoding.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot determine the total length of data to receive when using TCP/UDP. So you should implement a protocol over this underlying protocol to determine the total length to receive. So once you come to know the size, you expect and read those data.

Here, in your case of [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), the standard defines a separate header called `Content-Length` for the purpose of giving the total length of the **body**. But, to read the headers, you can receive arbitrary amount of data till you receive all headers and then the given amount of body content.

Read the [spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) to understand headers, body, delimiters..

Comment: Hello VoidPointer! I'm going to do it like this! Thanks for your quick help. Raptor

Answer (score 2):

Consider one of the two following approaches:

- Send the size of the data you want to transmit before the actual data. Use a fixed length format to transmit the size.
- Define any delimiter marking the end of the data, and continue reallocating the receive buffer until the delimiter had been received.

Comment: Hello alk, thanks for your quick response. That's exactly what I wanted. I'm now going to read the Http-Header field "Content-Length" for reallocating my buffer. Raptor

Comment: Nitpick: The size of the data doesn't necessarily need to be fixed-length, it can itself be delimited. This third option is how the "chunked" encoding works. Also, some formats (like well-formed XML) are self-delimiting and require no external delimiter.